# Getting runtime error 1004 after putting error handler?

Tags: vba, excel

Why does this not suppress errors?

```
For i = 1 To Last_row

    On Error GoTo errorhandler1
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=l)

    '' my code

errorhandler1:

next I
```

This is what I get:

[image: this the error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we begin, your code is not set up properly for error handling.

I found that once the `GoTo errohandler1` had been executed in the first instance, future calls were ignored so that's when the errors were thrown.

You current code is set up to ignore errors when opening workbooks, you can achieve this using `Resume Next`, and then `GoTo 0` to reset the error handling method.

```
    For i = 1 To Last_row

        On Error Resume Next
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=l)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not wkb Is Nothing Then
            '' my code
        End If
    next I
```

If you want to actually deal with errors -- rather than ignore them, you should do so outside of your loop (strongly encouraged!)

```
    For i = 1 To Last_row
        On Error GoTo CleanFail
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=l)
        '' my code
    next I

    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    'deal with error
```

Comment: thanks @callumDA. i add if statement in my workbook code and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`On Error GoTo` is more than just some kind of conditional `GoTo` jump.

When the runtime encounters an error, **it is in an error state** that you need to clear up.

An error-handling subroutine isn't just a label code jumps to in case of error - it's where you *handle runtime errors*.

By jumping to the `Next` statement you make that next iteration occur in a runtime error state, because you didn't `Clear` the error state ...so execution resumes and all the while, as far as VBA runtime is concerned, the loop body itself becomes the error-handling subroutine: VBA is waiting for `Err.Clear`, or `Resume Next`, or any other statement that tells it "all good, error is handled, move along, nothing to see here".

```
errorhandler1:
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    next i
```

That would fix the immediate problem, but still leave you with a quite convoluted spaghettish piece of code. Best extract the error-handling clean out of the "happy path".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you can't bypass a file not found error...

Try using a sub function to return the open file (if found) instead?

```
Function GetWorkBook(ByVal sFullName As String, Optional ReadOnly As Boolean) As Workbook
    Dim sFile As String: sFile = Dir(sFullName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorkBook = Workbooks(sFile)
    If GetWorkBook Is Nothing Then Set GetWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(sFullName, ReadOnly:=ReadOnly)
End Function
```